# jQuery method is not executed but with alert in front it does

Tags: jquery, methods, execution, timing

Hey Stackoverflowianers,

hope you're all well. My problem:

I try to alter some css on dynamically loaded elements. So I make an ajax-call, on success I write the resulting html to the depending elements and on complete I execute a function, which (by each) goes throug all these elements and changes some css.

The problem is:

1. it works, when I set an `alert('test')` right before the method, clicking it all through on execution
2. the code snippet works when I copy it to ff's console and execute it by hand
3. it doesn't work as expected when I comment out the `alert('test')` line... *grmlfx*

The first piece of code:

```
function fixRounded()
{
    $('img.round').each(function(){
        var w = $(this).css('width');
        var h = $(this).css('height');
        //alert('test');
        $(this).parent('div').parent('.imgr').css('background-size',w+' '+h).css('background-position','3px 3px');
        $(this).parent('div').parent('div').parent('.imgr').css('background-size',w+' '+h).css('background-position','3px 3px');
    });
}
```

The second piece of code is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "search_ajax.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
        $('#content').css('display', 'block');
        $('span.searchentry').text(searchbox);
        $("#searchResult"+what).html(html);
        $('#'+what+'-slider').catslider();
        roundImg();
    },
    complete: function()
    {
        fixRounded();
    }
});
```

I hope, I could explain my problem as understandable as possible. Please give me a hint in the right direction on how to solve this issue.

Best regards,

AceLine

Comment: put your fixRounded() inside the success.

Comment: I've updated my response. Can you try this and let us know if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that `fixRounded` gets executed before the elements have been appended to the DOM. The `alert` call, or using the console may cause a small delay but long enough for the elements to be appended completely.

Why don't you try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "search_ajax.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
        $('#content').css('display', 'block');
        $('span.searchentry').text(searchbox);
        $("#searchResult"+what).html(html);
        $('#'+what+'-slider').catslider();
        roundImg();
        fixRounded();
    }
});
```

---

Edit: I still think the problem is timing. Without a fiddle or proof of concept we won't know.

Try delaying the call further:

```
function fixRounded()
{
    $('img.round').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
        w = $this.css('width'),
        h = $this.css('height');

        $this.parents('.imgr').css({
            'background-size': w + ' ' + h,
            'background-position': '3px 3px'
        });
    });
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "search_ajax.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
        $('#content').css('display', 'block');
        $('span.searchentry').text(searchbox);
        $("#searchResult"+what).html(html);
        $('#'+what+'-slider').catslider();
        roundImg();
        setTimeout(fixRounded,1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you to for your fast reply!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Ast Derek's answer, you could use `promise` in place of complete. Use `done()` to execute the `fixRounded()` function:

```
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "search_ajax.php",
       data: dataString,
       cache: false,
       success: function(html)
       {
          $('#content').css('display', 'block');
          $('span.searchentry').text(searchbox);
          $("#searchResult"+what).html(html);
          $('#'+what+'-slider').catslider();
          roundImg();
       }
    }).done(fixRounded);
```

See docs of [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), [promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/), [done()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)

Comment: THNX a lot for fast response!!! @passionateCoder: sounded nice, but doesn't work... do you have any other idea?

Comment: no, no errors... I tried now }).promise().done(fixRounded); and wihthout the promise(), but no success.

Comment: I also tried it with a setTimeout of two seconds now but no success

Comment: @IngmarErdös you could comment the stuff in `fixRounded` an put an alert instead, then try using `done` , see if the alert fires.

Comment: alternatively, u could take the stuff inside `fixRounded` and paste it in `success` :)